# I haven't install GPS(GNAT Programming Studio) right

Tags: ide, ada, gnat-gps

I want to learn to program in Ada, yesterday I downloads GPS from Adacore website, extract the archive and run the "doinstall" file(I'm running OpenSuse 13.1). everything installed OK,I want to mention that I haven't edit the PATH variable, then I started Ada and create new project falling this guide 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Building-a-New-Program-with-GPS.html. Everything was good, I have written my Hello_World program, but when I tried to compile it I got those errors:

```
 Could not determine the project for file: /home/synchro/Ada_projects/hello.adb
 Could not expand argument in command line: %fp
 Build command not launched.
```

I was unable to find any information about how to fix this. Any help is welcome.

EDIT: I have add the file to the project Now I'm getting those errors:

```
 No file selected
 Could not expand argument in command line: %fp
 Build command not launched.
```

Comment: Yeah it's mistake sorry about that. Also I forget to say, that I didn't edit the PATH variable, I'm not sure should I do it and how.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to set your `PATH` so that `doinstall`’s suggestion comes first.

The file you have to edit to do this varies between Unix systems; Googling “how to set path in opensuse” suggests that the file you need to edit is `~/.profile` (that is, the file `.profile` - **note the leading period** - in your home directory).

Assuming `doinstall` said `/usr/local/gnat/bin`, you can probably get the effect you need by going to the end of the file and inserting the line

```
export PATH=/usr/local/gnat/bin:$PATH
```

(it may not be quite so simple if `~/.profile` contains conditional code down there) and then log out/log in.

---

This may fix your problem; I don’t recognise those error messages, so it could be something else.